# Error doing a keyword search using Facebook Graph API V2.5

Tags: java, api, facebook-graph-api

I am currently trying to use Facebook Graph API. As a rookie posting below questions. Please guide me...

I am using the below URL to do a simple test on a public keyword search using Facebook Graph API V2.5. I am just trying to do a simple keyword search as defined in the Guide.

I am using the Graph API Explorer and generated "user access token"

Request(with <> for accesstoken:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&access_token=
Response:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "GNqBnVm/8zd"
   }
}

Request(with out <> for access token:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&access_token=myUserAccessToken
Response:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 11,
      "fbtrace_id": "GPAno+jLwsu"
   }
}

Please help me understand what wrong am I doing here? the example is from the guide though. 
Q:If it is deprecated, what is the newer way of doing it?
Q: And what is the type of Access Token need to be used?
Q: Is it mandatory to also provide the appId and secret key as well, if I am not creating any app?
Q: Should I use <> for access token in the URL? The response is different with and without.

Appreciate your responses.

Thank You!
Danda

Comment: P.S. I did select All the check boxes/options under user data permissions and Extended permissions before generating the User Access Token.

Comment: you should not select all permissions for testing. only use those you need, the facebook docs tell you exactly which ones those are. you don´t need any additional permission for the search api though.

Comment: I did use the permissions just required in the beginning but it kept giving me the error "Invalid access token", so I thought of selecting all possible permissions just for the sake of it yet no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Public Post search is no longer available

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

There is no newer/other way. It just does not exist anymore.

There is only this, but you can´t apply - you can only work with one of the partners: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights

Comment: luschn, 
I understand the keyword_insights are depricated, but I see they provided the restApi with search functionality to replace it, right? I am trying to test just test that in the exact syntax and examples provided in the latest version(V2.5) but it gives the posted errors. 
If you have hands-on it, can you please try the URL below with your access token and see if you are able to perform the search successfully?
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&access_token=myUserAccessToken

Comment: what? where does it say that keyword_insights is deprecated? either way, it is only available through partners as you can read in the docs. there is no other way and there is no post/keyword search anymore. insights are just insights, nothing else. you don´t get posts, for example.

Comment: in other words: what you want to achieve is not possible, there is no replacement for the public post search.